# Question about cron behavior on Linux

Tags: cron, environment-variables

We have two Linux servers running with the same application and infrastructure/middleware setup (test and production), I want to run a health check program as a cron job every 2 minutes on server A like it already dose on server B.

What did I copy is the script from the sever B, implemented the script in the same directory in server A and added the job to Cron using `crontab -e`:

```
*/2 * * * * /opt/xxxx.sh arg1 arg2 >> test.txt 2>>err.txt
```

The output commands are just to see if the cron kicks the job.

The line which I added on crontab runs as expected individually on command line but it doesn’t execute as a cron job. When I added another job to cron (`echo >> test.txt kind of thing`), then it worked just fine.

- I changed the permission of the script to 755,
- When I exit the crontab editor it confirms the new installation.
- I have tried rebooting the server several times.

What do you think can I do more to make the health check run as a cron job?

There’s no output in `/var/log/cron`.

—————————————————

> Dear Martin Wood
>   Thank you. The program is written in Java but then it’s the shell script that runs the health check. 
>   I get no output by running:
>   run-parts /etc/cron.hourly -v
>   —————————————————

Comment: Are you getting any output (errors, warnings) in any of the log files?

Answer (score 0):

Does the script rely on dependencies such as Python or Ruby? Those will need permissions as well. You can test this with:

```
 run-parts /etc/cron.hourly -v
```

and see if it encounters any errors.
Run as root as this is the uid cron runs with.